# Angular 5 - Error on template: "Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'"

Tags: angular, build

When trying to build my Angular project using the command `ng build --prod --output-path <my_destination_path>`, I got few errors like the following:

```
ERROR in src/app/products/product-edit/product-edit.component.html(190,10): : Property 'length' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
```

The template product-edit.component.html: (error is on the 1st line)

```
<div *ngIf="productForm.get('seasons').length>0; else infoTextNoSeasons" formArrayName="seasons">
              <div class="row" *ngFor="let seasonCtrl of productForm.get('seasons').controls; let i = index"
          [formGroupName]="i">
                <div [class.col-xs-10]="i!=0">
                  <div [class.row]="i!=0">
                          <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="season">Season</label>
                            ...
```

Since the application is working fine using `ng serve`, I don't why Angular is not able to build it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the --prod flag, you're using the AOT compiler.

Unlike the JIT compiler, which runs in the browser and compiles the templates to JavaScript, the AOT compiler runs during the build, compiles the templates to TypeScript, and then the TypeScript to JavaScript.

So the TypeScript type checks apply, which allows discovering mistakes in the templates at compile time rather than runtime.

The error message tells you what's wrong: you're trying to access a `length` property from an AbstractControl, but AbstractControl doesn't have such a property. `length` only exists in FormArray, but TypeScript can't know that the AbstractControl is a FormArray. So, add a method in your component that uses a type assertion and returns the length.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I got it. FYI, I fixed changing `productForm.get('seasons').length>0` to `productForm.get('seasons')['length']>0`